# Getting currently logged-in user's ID in Firebase Auth in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, firebase-authentication

How do I get the currently logged in user's ID in Kotlin using Firebase Auth? I would like to take the ID to retrieve said user's complete information to display in an Activity.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the Firebase documentation on [getting the currently signed in user](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/manage-users#get_the_currently_signed-in_user):

> ```
> val user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser
> if (user != null) {
>     // User is signed in
> } else {
>     // No user is signed in
> }
> ```

Then you can get he user's UID with `user.uid` as shown in this example from the documentation on [getting the user's profile](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/manage-users#get_a_users_profile):

> ```
> val user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser
> user?.let {
>     // Name, email address, and profile photo Url
>     val name = user.displayName
>     val email = user.email
>     val photoUrl = user.photoUrl
>
>     // Check if user's email is verified
>     val emailVerified = user.isEmailVerified
>
>     // The user's ID, unique to the Firebase project. Do NOT use this value to
>     // authenticate with your backend server, if you have one. Use
>     // FirebaseUser.getToken() instead.
>     val uid = user.uid
> }
> ```

Comment: good one, saved my time

Answer (score 1):

```
val currentUser = Firebase.auth.currentUser
currentUser?.let {

// Name, email address, and profile photo Url
val name = currentUser.displayName
val email = currentUser.email
val photoUrl = currentUser.photoUrl

// Check if user's email is verified
val emailVerified = currentUser.isEmailVerified

// The user's ID, unique to the Firebase project. Do NOT use this value to
// authenticate with your backend server, if you have one. Use
// FirebaseUser.getToken() instead.
val uid = currentUser.uid
}
```